# .get() and .put() methods migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, xamarin

I am quite a .NET guy, developing in Xamarin. However, I got my hands on a piece of Java code for Android I would like to implement in C#. The problem is that the project was developed in Eclipse, and then ported to Android Studio and now cannot be compiled.

I got through all the issues with Gradle, but now I am stuck with some generated annotations and `.put()` and `.get()` methods, that cannot be referenced. There are many things similar to the following:

A normal interface like `MySharedPreferences` has its generated sealed (final) class counterpart `MySharedPreferences_`. This is then used in the code:

```
import com.someproject.MySharedPreferences_;

...

public class SomeAndroidClass {
    public MySharedPreferences_ prefs;

    public SomeMethod() {
        String x = prefs.someValue().get;
        ...
        prefs.someValue().put("abc");
    }
}
```

Now, this cannot be compiled, because the `MySharedPreferences_`class is not generated by Android studio. I tried to get rid of the underscore and use the `MySharedPreferences` interface instead. But then I had problem referencing the `.get()` and `.put()` methods. Please, can somebody help me how to deal with this problem?

**EDIT**

Adding the `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.0.0'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testproject.smartconfig"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your build.gradle file. Is that AndroidAnnotations?

Comment: Which one? There are two in the Android studio - for the project and  the app Module.

Comment: The app module one

Comment: MySharedPreferences_ is most likely class generated by Android Annotations library - http://androidannotations.org/, check if Your build.gradle contains needed config: https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle

Comment: I have tried that, but did not work... see the build.gradle file in the original post. The classes were generated in a new .apt_generated folder, but were not included into the project.

Comment: try to add .apt_generated as source folder, 
eq.   `sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'path/to/<YOUR DIRECTORY>'
    }`.

Alternatively try to reimport project but this time using gradle

Comment: I had to reimport the project. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySharedPreferences_ is most likely class generated by Android Annotations library - [androidannotations.org](http://androidannotations.org/), check if Your build.gradle contains needed config: https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle

Then reimport Your project using gradle.